# Google Oauth 2.0 not giving back authorization code

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client, google-oauth

I'm trying to follow this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

using the python client. I want to get the authorization code so I can exchange it for a refresh token.

However, when I make `flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(...)` and call `flow.step1_get_authorize_url()` , I automatically get the access token instead of the authorization code upon signing in, which is what I want. I'm requesting contacts scope and passing the following parameters:

```
access_type='offline',
approval_prompt='force',
include_granted_scopes='true'
```

I've searched online for a while on how to fix this problems, and most of them just suggest adding approval_prompt='force', which I already have.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show code and error response. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There's no error. It's just that I always get the access token back rather than an auth code, which is what I want, and which is what is promised in the API docs.

Comment: In the call back uri, provided that you've got the scopes requiring code exchange, the code should come back in the parameters of the get request from Google.  At that point you feed the parameters in to `flow.step2_exchange(params)` to get the token.  Are you saying that the code is not coming back in the parameters and that instead the token is being sent in the get parameters?